# How do I approach python argument passing instead of doing subprocess calls

Tags: python

So there's this package that I'm using, Automater (https://github.com/1aN0rmus/TekDefense-Automater) , and the developer for the package uses arguments to run the script.

```
python Automater.py {params}
```

but I'm trying to include this into my own application, and I'm trying to avoid altering his code. Is it possible to run Automater through my application?

I've tried doing

```
subprocess.call(["python", "automater/Automater.py", "params"])
```

but that didn't seem to even call the Automater. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

The hierarchy is:

```
myprogram.py
automater/Automater.py
__init__.py
```

I've made some modifications and I'm doing this instead

```
p = Popen(["python", "automater/Automater.py", query], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
print output, err, rc
```

But this is just printing 0 for error code with no other message to debug

Edit:

after further experimenting, turns out I have to be in the automater's directory for Automater.py to run properly, is there a way to do that in Python? i.e. move to directory -> run command

Comment: Is `automater/Automater.py` the local path to the script?

Comment: I will update with my hierarchy